# fedora 13 cannot enable desktop effect on thinkpad nvidia card?

Tags: fedora, desktop, graphics-processing-unit

according to [fedora 13 release notes](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Changes_in_Fedora_for_Desktop_Users.html#sect-Release_Notes-Fedora_Desktop), fedora should support desktop effect out of box with nvidia card. my laptop is thinkpad t61 w/ nvidia 140m. but i still cannot enable the desktop effect even with the mesa-dri-drivers-experimental installed. i know i could use some 3rd party driver, but i just want to make sure if there's nothing wrong with my system.

thanks,
david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia offer an excellent driver package from their own website. I have often found that using that package solved these problems. I really think it's worth a try.

Comment: i have not tried yet, but i believe this can solve my problem. thanks :)